# Operation of infinite switch

Tags: switches, temperature, resistance

Many electric stovetops are operated by an infinite switch, which pulses the current on and off for intervals determined by the dial setting. The actual control is effected via a bi-metal switch that moves as it is heated. I was wondering whether the temperature of the heating element has any effect on the timing of the switch. In other words, if I put a pot of cold water on the stove, thereby lowering the resistance of the element, will that speed up the heating of the bi-metal in the switch, causing it to stay on longer? Or is the bi-metal heated by a completely separate circuit?

Answer (score 2):

Very revised answer:

Very annoying.
 While my original answer to the original question was largely correct - ie the actual load in the element has no effect on timing, it was substantially wong in another area. I'll go back and edit everything in due course, but for now, original answer is left intact below.

I originally could not find a diagram of the internal connections of an "infinite switch" anywhere. Based on what is written elsewhere it sounded as if the heating coil connected across AC mains. However, this diagram which Dave found on [this very interesting fire investigation site](http://www.electrical-forensics.com/ElectricRanges/ElectricRange.html) tells a different story.

More detail below, but a surprising conclusion is that
 Doubling the element wattage will, for a given setting.

- reduce power by about 30% at high heat settings,
- reduce power output by 70% at low settings.
- reduce power output by 50% at medium settings.

You asked about affect of load (eg pot) on element power.
Notionally pot does not load element BUT I'd expect for a given power that element would get hotter due to loss of radiation path and some convection losses and pot reflection.
 If element is eg Nichrome this will not effect it. It will NOT have NTC so if it is mildly PTC (positive temperature coefficient of resistance) then res will rise with covering. Power in element = V^2/R so power will go down which will **TEND** to increase power level from the infinite switch as above. This should be a small effect and depends on Relement being PTC.

The above lower ower wity more Watts element effect suggest manufacturers may want to make switches to suit element powers.

The electronic circuit below dos not depend o an element in series with the element, unlike the mechanical one.

---

Background:

The switch's heater element is IN SERIES with the range element.When the heater is cold the switch is on and the range element will be turned on. The heating energy will be governed by the element current which will depend on the element' Wattage. So doubling the wattage doubles the current.
 HOWEVER the series heater will only dissipate a small percentage of the main voltage and the voltage drop across the heater element will be proportional to current if the heater resistance remains constant. As a consequence heater watts
will rise with the square of the current. So doubling element wattage increases heater power by 4 times. If on time is approximately proportional to heater power then doubling element wattage will reduce on time by a factor of 4. Off time can be expected to be close to constant as temperature at turnoff will presumably be similar and cooling time should be largely unrelated to heating rate. So, imagine that a controller was running at 66 time units on, 34 time units off. Doubling element wattage can be expected to reduce on time to about 16 time units. So duty cycle goes from 66/99 = 2/3 = 0.666 to 16/5= = 0.32 or 2:1. That sounds very good.
 BUT if originally running at say 20:80 = 0.20 it would change to 5/85 = 0.06 or 30% of original.
 At the other extreme, of running at 90:10 = 0.90 it would change to 70 % of original.
 ie Doubling the element wattage will
 reduce power by about 30% at high heat settings,
 reduce power output by 70% at low settings.
 reduce power output by 50% at medium settings.

This means that a higher Wattage element will reduce output for a given setting and have an increasing rate of getting hot a the top end.

[image]

=================================

No - the temperature of the heating element or an item being heated has no effect on these controls.  Here in New Zealand one name they are called is a  "simmerstat" or an "energy regulator"- they will probably have other names elsewhere.

They are what is known as "open loop" controls. Only the dial setting controls the on/off ratio - the load or target object is NOT "sensed". As the dial is turned the on/off or mark-space ratio changes.

Controllers do exist that take account of the target temperature. This is usually termed a thermostat if you are heating air. These also may use a bimetallic strip but it is controlled by the target air temperature.

---

Here is an elecronic simmerstat control schematic. Note that they could sense load power but have chosen not to. OM1895 IC - diagram [from here](http://www.hendonsemiconductors.com/om1895.asp).

[10 page application  note](http://www.hendonsemiconductors.com/_data/docs/hm177-datasheet.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But why, indeed, would the change in resistance not affect the rate at which the bimetallic strip heats up (albeit slightly)?

Comment: As I understand what is done, the "heater" is driven by a small heating coil powered from the AC mains. While the mains MAY sag slightly when the load is switched on they are not meant to do so perceptibly. If it did affect the result it would be a weak 2nd order effect and not designable. Load current dependance coukd be added if desired but I'm not aware that it is.

Comment: This schematic is way more complex than the infinite switches I've seen. All that's inside of them is a plastic cam and a few metal strips. Not even anything that might function as a heater.

Comment: Oh, I see from this site (http://www.electrical-forensics.com/ElectricRanges/ElectricRange.html) that there is in fact a small heater on one of the strips.

Answer (score 1):

Infinite switches are not thermostatic controls. They regulate the percent of time the controlled heating element is on. All infinite switches use a nichrome heater wire or ribbon and a bimetal strip to open and close the electrical connection to the heating element being controlled. The shaft of the control has an eccentric that varies pressure on the bimetal strip to encourage the switch contacts to remain closed until the bimetal is hotter as the control is set to higher settings. 
Infinite switch controls frequently have “pilot” contacts for an indicator light. The pilot contacts are closed whenever the switch is not “off”, and they do not cycle with the control’s  regulating contacts. The pilot circuit may be either a single terminal connection to line power shared with the heating control or a pair of terminals for an isolated low current switch.

All infinite switches rely on a presumed similarity between the rate at which the internal element heats and cools and the heating element being controlled. The infinite switch is characterized by a control curve that shows the percentage of time the controlled heater is “on” vs shaft angle. Home cooking ranges are typically 5% on at the lowest setting. The on/off curve is exponential, rising slowly at first and rapidly as the highest setting is approached. Because an open pan radiates heat exponentially more rapidly as it gets hotter, and exponential heat input vs shaft angle results in a control where the temperature of an open pan is linearly proportional to the shaft angle.

The internal construction of the control either connects the heater in series with the controlled element or in parallel with it. A series connection causes on-time to be proportional the current in the controlled element which is the line voltage divided by the temperature dependent resistance of the element while a parallel connection is proportional only to the line voltage. The parallel connection delivers more power to a lower resistance cool element, while the series connection delivers less.

The end result for the user is that it’s easier to adjust a series connected control to achieve a desired vigor of boiling and the control positions for a particular task are less dependent on the local utility line voltage at that moment. The constraint is that the series connected control has to contain a heating element that matches the power rating of the controlled heating element instead of one that matches the national standard voltage.

The advantage of the parallel connected control is that it’s independent of the resistance or rated wattage of the controlled element. That allows a range to have reconfigurable cartridges e.g. one with different wattage surface elements can be exchanged with one that has equal wattage elements for a grill or a round bottom Wok. The disadvantage is that the control regulates on time percentage, not power input of temperature so the control setting for a particular task depends on the line voltage (which varies during the day) and its more difficult to control the power input when the temperature of the heating element is held constant, for example by a boiling liquid.

Thermostatic control’s - more than 50 years ago there were electric ranges that featured thermostatically controlled burners, one by Frigidaire, then owned by General Motors, comes to mind. A capillary sensing element was housed in the center of the calrod coil in a spring loaded button that made contact with the center of the cooking pan. The small capillary bulb volume meant the normal leak rate resulted it 1/4 or 1/3 the life of an oven thermostat with roughly the same repair cost, and the costly feature was only useful for frying and such, so the feature remained uncommon.

Electronic (thryistor) control; an obvious question would be why wasn’t the heater and bimetal switch device rendered obsolete by a simple thryistor SCR or Triac dimmer? Wouldn’t that allow direct IR photodiode temperature feedback? Unfortunately, as obviously promising as this idea is, a couple of practical problems have made it uncommon. The typical ambient temperature spec for an infinite heat control is around 200°F. The semiconductor based control’s reliability is poor at elevated ambient temperatures and it doesn’t tolerate ambient heat/cool cycles 3x a day well. More than 40 years after the first products a semiconductor based control with equal reliability remains much more expensive than the electromechanical control, and no one has figured out a good way to use a photodiode to peek at the temperature of a pan if you put the lid on. The IR emissivity of a clean shiny metal pan is too much lower than one that’s smoked glass or slightly dirty for IR temperature sensing from the bottom to be acceptably accurate. With very limited application advantages a higher cost lower reliability control isn’t an advantage.

Answer (score 0):

i repair commercial food service equipment for a living now. Before I worked as an electronics technician repairing all sorts of pcb assemblies for 20 years.  then i found that while more and more circuit boards were becoming disposable, they are not disposable if mounted and integral to a $15k to $45k piece of food service equipment.

Today I had to nail down exactly what was wrong with an infinite switch controlled heater that I had previously worked on.  Truns out I had misplaced a wire.  Even I make an occaisional error.

Anyway to make the point I am here to make: the heater in the infinite switch resides in paralled with contacts H1 and H2.  not in series between the bimetal switch and H2 as shown in the drawing above.  You can prove this by removing the good working infinite switch from the circuit, allow it to cool to room temperature, set the shaft in the off position then measure resistance with your DVM across H1 and H2. the 1.2k ohms you read ( or thereabouts depending on the switch's voltage rating ) will be the internal heater.

if your switch is different, I would like to hear about thst.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with JohnG that the heater of SOME infinite switch might connect to H1 and H2 directly. Switches for high wattage and low wattage elements are interchangeable for this kind of design.

However, most infinite switches designed for low wattage elements will work erratically with high wattage elements. The high wattage element will never reach its desired temperature on any settings other than the maximum when the contacts stay closed all the time. The reason is because heater of this infinite switch connects in series with the element. Since the current drawn by the high wattage element is higher than that designed for the low wattage switch, the bimetal will open the contacts sooner than required to reach the expected temperature.

Answer (score 0):

The Robert Shaw switches I just repaired put the heater coil for the bimetallic strip in parallel with the burner, connected between H1 and H2. Resistance or current changes in the burner would cause little change to the current in the heater coil. With switch off, heater coil  measured 15kOhms. Marked INF240P, the switch is marked 15A and seems to work equally well with both burner sizes. Note: Shafts are interchangeable (disassembly required) between similar switches, allowing existing mounts (2 screws or 1 shaft nut) and existing shafts ( D-shaped or H-shaped) to be reused.

Open-circuit heaters don't seem repairable, being foil blankets under hi-temp wrap possibly with an asbestos sleeve.

Answer (score 0):

The switch design and naming convention is unusual for an electrical device, and I found this expired patent.  Its likely George Sekera invented and patented it, as even the unusual name is given.  The current manufacture of the switch is still much like the original drawings; all functional descriptions are all described in the patent.  All interested in the workings of the switch thus, should peruse the patent document.

https://patents.google.com/patent/US4052591

Answer (score 0):

With the Triac switch, fire may occur when the Triac fails short circuit which is the most failures you will see. It happened to me but luckily enough I was there and turned panel power off.