# Is matching an infinite switch rating to a heating element required?

Tags: switches, ac, safety, heat

I want to use a [Robertshaw universal infinite switch](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00308ZKEU) rated at 15 Amps to power a heating element to boil water in a stainless steel tub. The voltage is 240 VAC. A heating element greater than 3600W will draw more than 15 amps when the switch is on. My understanding is that the infinite switch will turn off as often as required to deliver an average of 15 Amps continuous at the maximum setting and will not turn off at the maximum setting if the heating element is less than 3600W. Is it safe to connect a 5500W heating element that draws more than 20 Amps and run it at the maximum setting of the switch with wiring sized for 20 Amps?

Comment: link to product would be appreciated

Comment: It sounds like you want a current-limit switch which self-limits to the "rated" amps, I doubt what you describe is what's happening/will happen. I think you are going to blow stuff up. I don't know exactly what the switch is/does though so this is just guessing

Comment: @KyranF Link Provided

Comment: Infinite switches are specifically designed to control heater element loads on stovetops.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be what they call a "simmerstat" or stove control over here (UK) where "infinite" just means its on-off ratio is continuously variable from "low" to 100%. It has no current-limiting function, but its switch contacts are rated to safely conduct (and disconnect) 15A.

For your purpose, treat it as any other 15A rated switch. That means, if you switch a 20A load with it, expect its contacts to burn out eventually, or weld themselves shut delivering full power to the load until all the water has boiled away and the 240V heating element melted inside the metal container.

Comment: Based on what I read about simmerstats in http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21420/operation-of-infinite-switch?rq=1 I don't think we're talking about the same thing.

Comment: Linked in comments there : http://www.electrical-forensics.com/ElectricRanges/ElectricRange.html - their "infinite heat switch" is exactly the same thing.